# Solution of the differential equation $y'' + 2xy' + \left( 1 + x^2 \right)y = 0$ via power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Given the differential equation $$y'' + 2xy' + \left( 1 + x^2 \right)y = 0$$ find its general solution.

Since I know no direct method to find solution without the knowledge of one of the linearly independent solutions, I went for finding the solution with series expansion method. The two solutions, which I eventually achieved were:-

$$y_1 = 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \dfrac{x^4}{8} - \dfrac{x^6}{48} + ...$$

$$y_2 = x - \dfrac{x^3}{2} + \dfrac{x^5}{8} - \dfrac{x^7}{48} + ...$$

I would like to know if these two solutions can be written is the form of some standard functions.

I have some intuition about their series that $y_1$ can be written as $y_1 = \cos \left( f(x)\right)$, where $f(x)$ is some function of $x$. Similarly, $y_2$ can be written in the form $y_2 = xy_1 = x \cos \left( f(x) \right)$. I would like to know this $f(x)$ (if all the intuitions I have are correct).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So $y_1$ is
$$y_1 = 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \dfrac{x^4}{8} - \dfrac{x^6}{48} + ...$$
Putting in summation form
$$y_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{n!\cdot2^n}$$
Now, we know that
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!} \quad (1)$$
and replacing $x \to \frac{-x^2}{2}$ in $(1)$ yields
$$e^\frac{-x^2}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{n!\cdot2^n}$$
Hence, we find our solutions are given by 
$$y_1 =e^\frac{-x^2}{2}$$
and

$$y_2 =xe^\frac{-x^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$z:=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,y\,.$$
Then, $$z'=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,y'+x\,\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,y$$
and
$$z''=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,y''+2\,x\,\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,y'+\left(1+x^2\right)\,\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,y\,.$$
That is,
$$z''=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,\Big(y''+2\,x\,y'+\left(1+x^2\right)\,y\Big)=0\,.$$
Hence,
$$z=a\,x+b$$
for some constants $a$ and $b$.  This means
$$y=\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,\left(a\,x+b\right)\,.$$

---

Alternatively, write $D:=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$.  Then, for an arbitrary differentiable function $f$ (on the variable $x$), we have
$$(D-f)^2=D^2-2\,f\,D+f^2-f'\,.$$
In particular, when $f(x)=-x$, we have
$$(D+x)^2=D^2-2\,x\,D+\left(x^2+1\right)\,.$$
Hence, we are to solve $(D+x)^2\,y=0$.  First, let $w:=(D+x)\,y$.  We obtain
$$w'=-x\,w\,,$$
and it follows immediately that
$$w=a\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$
for some constant $a$.  That is,
$$y'+x\,y=(D+x)y=w=a\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$
so that
$$D\,\Biggl(\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,y\Biggr)=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,\left(y'+x\,y\right)=a\,.$$
This shows that
$$\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,y=a\,x+b$$
for some constant $b$.  Ergo,
$$y=\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,\left(a\,x+b\right)\,.$$